# Keep filled form data with pdfpages

Tags: pdfpages, forms

I have to fill pdf forms for a school asigment and would like to append them to my final report. Yet, when using `\includepdf` from the `pdfpages` package,
all the information I fill into the form disapears (i.e: checkboxes and text-boxes).

How could I prevent that information from disapearing?

Thanks!

Comment: Pdfpages uses \includegraphics, which treats PDFs as images.  Forms are a whole other level of complexity.

Comment: As an experiment, I opened a form with Gimp and was able to export it as a JPEG (data intact).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Print them to pdf first and then include the newly created pdf. This way it will have all the data from the fields.

- mac supports print to pdf natively
- windows+unix: there are many programs to print files to pdf